# Android controls/layouts (How Instagram app does do that?)

Tags: android, android-layout, instagram

I would want to know that how Instagram application listing/showing feed page?

Here is a screenshot: (I found it via Google and resized via tinypic.com. Here is the original file: http://www.digitaltrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/screenshotsjvc.jpg)

[image: instagram screenshots]

I am talking about 1st and 2nd screens.

As you know, when you go your feed (2nd screen) you can slide down and view other shares.

Every share has these:

- Owner picture and username, shared time, a photo and a few things.

How to wrap all these datas in one control/layout in order to multiply?

Which control(s) (LinearLayout, Fragment, TableLayout and its TableRow(s)) are relevant for this kind of application?

I am not an expert Android application developer, that's why I want to know. I have confusion about that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding screen 1 and screen 2 probably different fragments (take a look about fragments [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)). 1st fragment contains [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) (or some similar control) and 2nd one contains [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).

I would suggest to begin with [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html). Basically, You will need to develop layout for single item (I think single [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) might be appropriate here) and then use it as item in the adapter.