# Facebook's Android app (How to do?)

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to figure out the best way to develop an android application nowadays. That's why I want to learn using relevant controls/layouts when developing an application.

My previous question was about Instagram's Android application. [At here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577529/android-controls-layouts-how-instagram-app-does-do-that).

Current question is about Facebook's.

[image: FB Android app - settings part]

I am wondering how Facebook app doing that, via which control? When you slide screen left on Facebook app, settings panel will be shown.

Is it an activity/frame/table or something else? How this app separates screen to two?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a slide menu, you can use the Navigation Drawer that Google just introduced at the Google I/O 2013, is included in the Support Library.

Design
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Example tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: it doesn't slide out the content, but instead, it slides OVER the content

Answer (score 2):

You must use Android Drawers.

You will find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12027980/1832221).

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are using HTML5 for this purpose. Checkout this :

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/#

Comment: This should be easy to tell, place your google device into debug mode and and enable the view boundaries options. If it is html5 in a webview it will only have one box for the entire thing.